# How to pass an array from a c++ library to c#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, plugins, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a plugin for [this](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/) c++ physics library for Unity3d. The library is a superset of Box2D with particle simulation added.
In the c++ library there is a function that returns an array of 2d vector objects for all the particles.
I'm wondering how I could pass this back to Unity so I can draw them? I Cant pass objects between the library and Unity. Could I pass a 2d array of floats? I heard that I should instantiate an array of the correct size in Unity in c#, then pass it to the c++ function where all the data will be filled in, then pass it back to Unity (this is to help avoid memory problems in c++) How would you write this in c++?
Alternatively could I use an out paramater to do this? And how would you write that?

Comment: may this two link helps you .its msdn corner link is http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32f1a857-91d6-472d-b333-469ed7f6f6dd/passing-a-byte-array-to-a-c-dll-from-c

Comment: C++ to C# use CoTaskMemAlloc family of functions on the C++ side. You can find information about this on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the method in your C# code as returning `IntPtr` and then convert it to the array you need (an array of the managed version of the objects you have in your C++ code) .